# Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 - improper use of do-release-upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

I started an upgrade from  Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 but did not follow the proper procedure. The sequence of commands I executed are:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

At this point, instead of pressing "enter" to continue with the update I hit "ctrl c" and exited the above command, then I ran the following three commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

The last three commands caused a number of updates to occur, and it looks like they were updates for 18.04 but I believe my computer is still running on 16.04

My computer still seems to run fine (I have not tried rebooting).

My question: Can I still complete an upgrade to 18.04? If yes, how do I do this? Or, have I really messed things up and it is best to leave things as is?

Comment: The use of `-y` with `dist-upgrade` is very dangerous.

Comment: You've not said if this is a server or desktop system, if it was a desktop system, I'd recommend just *upgrade via re-install* (ie. non-destructive re-install; where the lack of format triggers a repair installation, but using 18.04; also if internet is available during install, your *manually installed* or added packages will auto-reinstall if available for new release in Ubuntu repositories).  To fix your situation you'd need work out where you were up to & continue from there; but it's not clear.  What was machine doing when you hit ^C  What did you see when you first ran `apt update`..

Comment: Your use of `-y` was very wrong in my opinion; you needed to read messages & deal with whatever was provided; where `-y` in your messages implied you'd already done your homework by checking before commands were executed, and corrected any problems before hand. The use of `-y` has made your situation I suspect, far worse & I'd read back what you agreed to with the `-y` and is there something you need to walk back etc...  I'd opt for re-install if you didn't do your homework prior to `-y` commands being executed.

Answer (score 1):

I see no problems with what you did.

With your commands you installed regular updates for 16.04. Then you cancelled a release upgrade.

Now you can run `do-release-upgrade`.